# Adding a few lines of information to a grid

Tags: google-sheets

I have made out an 8 column, 21 lines,  informative health chart with grid lines.

I would like to add an afterthought running from left to right UNDER the grid lines that will PRINT out with the finished chart.

The Columns are too narrow to contain an afterthought.
The NOTE and COMMENT will not print out with the Chart and they are little boxes, rather than a couple of lines from left to right.  I cannot find any footnote on the chart site to see if it would appear just under the grid line ending.

How do I type a few lines of text, running from left to right, under the grid lines of the finished Chart that will print out on the finished Chart.   Example below:

```
--------  -------  -------  -------  ------  ------    columns
-----------------------------------------------------  end of grid line
```

Please keep the replies simple, I'm not experienced at spread-sheeting.

Comment: Can you share a doc with us?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the Horizontal axis label area;

[image: WA40726 example]